# Cygwin - in `utc': time out of range (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, cygwin

I'm getting the following on a fresh Cygwin Ruby install (via Cygwin's setup.exe) on Windows 8.1:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-cygwin]

$ ruby
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:103:in `utc': time out of range (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:103:in `<class:Specification>'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1203:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1203:in `<module:Gem>'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:115:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

Any hints on how to fix this?

Lines 102 and 103 read:

```
today = Time.now.utc
TODAY = Time.utc(today.year, today.month, today.day) # :nodoc:
```

Comment: That's very odd. What is your date set to? It also might be worth looking into those files at the associated lines to see if anything obvious turns up.

Comment: `
$ date
Thu, Sep  4, 2014  8:28:12 PM
`

Comment: Hrm, damnit! This just **disappeared...** - what the hell?

Comment: It's not even a special day today like February 29th. That's very odd.

Comment: OK; adding some debugging yields some very strange stuff:

`p Time.now # 2014-09-04 22:17:42 +715936124`
`p Time.now.zone # "3\x83\x89I\u0004"`

Comment: That's a time-zone offset of 817 years in the future. What's it like living in the year 2831? Something's very wrong with your time-zone setting, or perhaps your `TZ` environment variable.